# C++11 Threads: condition variable leads to an unexpected behaviour

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to sync two threads using condition_variable in c++11.
I'm a using eclipse under ubuntu, and everything is compiled with g++.
Both threads are in the same class.
The first thread increments a private variable of the class:

```
void Test::test::Loop()
{
    int loops = 48;
    while (loops > 0)
    {

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(this->m);
        this->index++;

        // Simulate work
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

        this->Processed = true;
        this->c.notify_one();

        loops--;

    }

    return;
}
```

As a first test I'd like to display this->index in the other thread:

```
void Test::test::Process()
{

    while(this->ProcessData)
    {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->m);

        while(!this->Processed)
            this->c.wait(lock);

        printf("\n%d", this->index);
        fflush(stdout);

        this->Processed = false;

        this->m.unlock();
        this->c.notify_one();

    }

     return;
}
```

I also tried with this->c.wait(lock, [this] { return this->Processed;}).
The result is that the program displays only the number 48 [edit the displayed number is 48, not 1], and never stops...
What am I doing wrong?
This is the fist time I really used condition_variable, but as far as I understood c.notify_one() should allow the second thread to display the variable for each iteration.

Sorry if the question's already been asked, but I didn't really find anything similar. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does changing the loop's `lock_guard` to `unique_lock` help? Shouldn't you also remove the explicit `this->m.unlock();`? Isn't that what `unique_lock` does in its destructor?

Comment: I don't think using `this->m.unlock` inside the scope of `std::unique_lock lock` is correct/legal.

Comment: I commented the unlock, it doesn't make any difference. Changing lock_guard to unique_lock doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: Don't know if that helps but, in Debug mode it looks like the second thread never joins. Here is my code http://freewebmaster.fr/up/cpp/test_Threads1.zip (make all in the Debug folder). Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want the loops to alternate possession of the lock, so 1 iteration of `Loop()` executes then 1 iteration of `Process()`. But there is no "fairness" requirement in the mutex and locks, so when `Loop()` releases the lock it can get it right back again. Nothing says "`Process()` should get the lock next because it has been waiting". The way you have written your code, `Loop()` can iterate once, twice, or even 48 times before `Process()` acquires the lock.

Comment: Thanks @rhashimoto! That's how I should have asked the question actually... How do I say that I want to alternate the possession of the lock?

Comment: The easiest modification to your code is probably to insert a wait on the condition variable in `Loop()` while `this->Processed`. But having two functions synchronized like this wouldn't be a good use of multi-threading in the first place. Perhaps you'll want to explore using a queue to pass information between threads with less coupling.

Comment: Thanks! It almost works. I though about the queue, and it's probably the best solution for what I want to do, but I wanted to understand why that code wasn't working. I still have a problem though. The second thread doesn't stop. Here's the debugger output: [New Thread 0xb7ca5b40 (LWP 29481)]
[New Thread 0xb74a4b40 (LWP 29482)]
[Thread 0xb7ca5b40 (LWP 29481) exited].
By the way, can you explain why having two methods synchronized isn't a good use of multi-threading ?

Comment: Why would the second thread ever stop? It enters the loop if `ProcessData` is true. Nothing ever changes `ProcessData` so it never exits the loop. As for why making these loops run in lock-step this way isn't advisable, the reason is you don't get the benefit of any parallel execution - the only time anything useful is happening is when the lock is being held, and the lock can only be held by one thread at a time. If you are going to add the complexity and cost of multi-threading, you need an approach where your threads can do useful work concurrently.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your help. I'll use either a queue or a ring buffer, we'll see.